# Travelling to Pakistan on expiring passport

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passports, us-citizens, pakistani-citizens, pakistan

I have a US passport valid for several years, and a Pakistani passport expiring mid-August. I'd like to travel from the US to Pakistan and back in March.

Can the Pakistani immigration authorities create issues as my Pakistan passport is expiring in less than 6 months of when I want to **exit Pakistan**.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you a Pakistani citizen?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I don't _think_ this is a dupe, since this question asks about leaving Pakistan on a passport that's about to expire, whereas the other is about entering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they cannot.

You can enter the country on the day your passport expires - as it is still valid till midnight of that day.

On exit, they do not check when your passport is about to expire.

As long as your passport is the new electronic kind, with the MRZ you'll be fine.

Enjoy your trip.

Answer (score 4):

The 3 or 6 months rules is to be sure that you doesn't stay in a foreign country.  This is not your case, because Pakistan is also your country.  In general, one is always allowed to enter in own country, with or without documents.  The problem not having documents: immigration should check from other sources that you are really the person you tell them you are.

A expired passport will cause some issues, because it should be checked further about forgery etc., but it will not cause deny to enter on own country, and it is not your case: your passport is valid on entire your stay, so it legitimate you also in Pakistan.

The problem usually arise before arriving to "home country": you could have problem with the airline.  But in your case: you are "returning home", and your document is still valid, so they should not care.

Comment: Even if the document was expired there would be no problems entering his own country. The Pakistani authorities can easily check if a person is Pakistani by running his/her biographic and biometric information through the NADRA database